# Xamarin Forms Switch IsToggled Binding NRE on Toggle [Android]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

For some reason, I am not able figure out why exactly this view in my Switch just looks weird and crashes on Toggle.

Here is the exact behaviour:

- if IsToggled is false, it can toggle it to true fine and works as expected.
- if IsToggled is true, it looks weird(missing its Track) and on toggle, it crashes with 2 uncaught exceptions(no stacktrace available).

I also tried to catch the problem via breakpoints and an uncaught exception handler, but with no luck there.

I linked a screenshot(I cut the lower part because it is not relevant)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQq9P.jpg

Using Xamarin Forms 3.1.0.583944 and this problem only occurs on Android(for now I can test it on android 8 only. Later, I hope I get my fingers on a android 7 or 6 device, I'll update here then)

Did anyone come across this problem before? I could not find any related help on google.

Thank you for all tipps and ideas in advance!

**edit**: here is the control declaration in XAML:

```
<Switch Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" IsToggled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Toggled="Switch_OnToggled" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked, Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

**edit 2**: changed Topic (should be more clear now)

**edit 3**: i could track the NRE via logcat down to: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/SwitchRenderer.cs#L120

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish with this Switch?  Binding of IsEnabled to IsToggled seems unusual, and I could imagine it causing problems in renderers.

Comment: I Finally figured it out. it was a known bug in Xamarin forms. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who face this issue too:

This problem was related to a Xamarin.Forms Issue. Updating Xamarin.Forms to the recent version(as of August 20th) fixed this problem.